# List Pages on Admin Menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, admin

I am trying to make my clients dashboard as simple as possible. Is there a way to do a [`wp_list_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) down the left side of the admin menu? Instead of clicking on Pages first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a matter of using [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) with [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page).

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_pages_so_19817501' );

function admin_pages_so_19817501() 
{
    $pages = get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
    foreach( $pages as $p )
    {
        add_submenu_page(
            'edit.php?post_type=page',
            $p->post_title,
            $p->post_title,
            'edit_pages',
            '/post.php?post='.$p->ID.'&action=edit',
            null
        );
    }
}
```

You'll need some jQuery to manipulate the `current` CSS class from the submenu items.
See: [Highlighting a Menu Item by Post Name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/59050/12615).